# Transaction not getting confirmed on local cluster

Tags: solana-cli, local-cluster

I am trying to create a local cluster using scrips available on solana repository. I am testing using v1.11.9.

I use the script `multinode-demo/setup.sh` to create a genesis block.
Then i use the scripts `multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh` and `multinode-demo/faucet.sh` to start the bootstrap validator and faucet.

After starting the bootstrap validator and faucet I am using using following command to use solana with my local cluster.
`solana config set --url http:\\127.0.0.1:8899`

I get correctly the transaction count, slot and the balance of the bootstrap validator identity using solana cli.

When I do airdrop on an address the faucet accepts the airdrop request but the validator does not process it. And i get confirmation error on the solana cli.
Same thing happen when i use transfer command to transfer some sol from bootstrap validator identity to another account.

In both cases I get following error :
`Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds.`

When i use the `solana-test-validator` i do not have this issue.

Comment: After some testing I found out that, If i download a solana version using `solana-version init` solana-test-validator works fine. But if i build solana source from source even solana-test-validator has same problem.

Comment: I also found a wierd issue that compiling on master branch we do not get the same issue, but compiling a specific version v1.14.3 I have the same issue. Seems to be related to QUIC.

Comment: I have created an issue for this comment : https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/28191

Comment: Hello I was able to achieve this with latest version, also did you tried to add validators to the local cluster ? I am facing slot synching issue while doing so. Can you help me on this ?

Comment: @Galactus Godmode how can I make this work with 1.13.7? I have a local cluster I cannot make finalize a transaction...

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, solana should be compiled with a specific version of rust because of quinn. You cannot compile solana with the latest rust compiler.

So when you compile solana instead of doing :

```
cargo build
```

It is better to do :

```
./cargo build
```

Check for whole conversation : https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/28191